# Best way to access a value from a different .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 javascript files, `inputs.js` and `files.js`. I'm trying to access the value of the file from the object `askingInputs` from `inputs.js`, but I'm not being able to do so.

These are what I have:

### Inputs.js

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
module.exports = {
  askingInputs: () => {
    const questions = [
      {
        name: "command",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter the command to be executed:",
        validate: function (value) {
          if (value.length) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return "Invalid command.";
          }
        },
      },
      {
        name: "file",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter file to be analized:",
        validate: function (value) {
          if (value.length) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return "File doesn't exist";
          }
        },
      },
    ];
    return inquirer.prompt(questions);
  },
};
```

### Files.js

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
module.exports = {
  askingInputs: () => {
    const questions = [
      {
        name: "command",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter the command to be executed:",
        validate: function (value) {
          if (value.length) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return "Invalid command.";
          }
        },
      },
      {
        name: "file",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter file to be analized:",
        validate: function (value) {
          if (value.length) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return "File doesn't exist";
          }
        },
      },
    ];
    return inquirer.prompt(questions);
  },
};
```

Thank you for any idea you can provide. I've trying with different exports options but I either get undefined or that the value doesn't exist, I have also checked I'm exporting the correct file from require.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don’t export anything from the index file. Bad practice. Better create a file `global.js` to keep exports that you want in index.js.

To import in your node version you then need to do:

```js
const global = require(‘./global.js’)
```

### ES6 Default Export

```js
// index.js

import File from ‘./file.js’

let f = new File()
console.log(f.name)

// file.mjs OR
// file.js with “type”: “module” in package file.

export default function File () {
   this.name = “src”
}

// instead of function can also be object,
// class, or a variable declaration.
```

### ES6 Multiple Exports

```js
// index.js

import { File, TextFile } from ‘./file.js’

let f = new File()
let tf = new TextFile()

// file.mjs OR
// file.js with “type”: “module” in package file.

export function File () {
   this.name = “src”
}

export function TextFile (t) {
   this.name = “src”
   this.content = t
}

// instead of function can also be object,
// class, or a variable declaration.
```

### ES5

```
// index.js

const k = require(‘./file.js’)

// file.js (Default export)

exports.default = ...

// file.js (Multiple Exports)

exports.File = function () {
   this.name = “src”
}

exports.TextFile = function (t) {
   this.name = “src”
   this.content = t
}
```